# How to merge two RGBA images

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to merge two RGBA images (with a shape of (h,w,4)), taking into account their alpha channels.
**Example :**
[image: example]

---

### What I've tried

I tried to do this using opencv for that, but I getting some strange pixels on the output image.

**Images Used:**

[image: image1.png]

and

[image: image2.png]

```python
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image1 = cv2.imread("image1.png", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
image2 = cv2.imread("image2.png", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

mask1 = image1[:,:,3]
mask2 = image2[:,:,3]
mask2_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(mask2)

mask2_bgra = cv2.cvtColor(mask2, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGRA)
mask2_inv_bgra = cv2.cvtColor(mask2_inv, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGRA)

# output = image2*mask2_bgra + image1
output = cv2.bitwise_or(cv2.bitwise_and(image2, mask2_bgra), cv2.bitwise_and(image1, mask2_inv_bgra))
output[:,:,3] = cv2.bitwise_or(mask1, mask2)
plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(output, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2RGBA))
plt.axis('off')
```

**Output :**
[image: output]

So what I figured out is that I'm getting those weird pixels because I used **cv2.bitwise_and** function (Which btw works perfectly with binary alpha channels).
I tried using different approaches

---

### Question

Is there an approach to do this (While keeping the output image as an 8bit image).

Comment: Keeping the output image as an 8bit provides by : output.astype(np.uint8). Feel free to convert your images to float type.

Comment: After converting to float type, split both rgba images. Compute weight masks as m1 = alpha1/(alpha1+alpha2) and m2=alpha2/(alpha1+alpha2). The result = img1*alpha1 + img2*alpha2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to obtain the expected result in 2 stages.

```
# Read both images preserving the alpha channel
hh1 = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\524316\Desktop\Stack\house.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)  
hh2 = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\524316\Desktop\Stack\memo.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)   

# store the alpha channels only
m1 = hh1[:,:,3]
m2 = hh2[:,:,3]

# invert the alpha channel and obtain 3-channel mask of float data type
m1i = cv2.bitwise_not(m1)
alpha1i = cv2.cvtColor(m1i, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGRA)/255.0

m2i = cv2.bitwise_not(m2)
alpha2i = cv2.cvtColor(m2i, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGRA)/255.0

# Perform blending and limit pixel values to 0-255 (convert to 8-bit)
b1i = cv2.convertScaleAbs(hh2*(1-alpha2i) + hh1*alpha2i)
```

***Note:*** In the b=above the we are using only the inverse alpha channel of the memo image

[image]

But I guess this is not the expected result. So moving on ....

```
# Finding common ground between both the inverted alpha channels
mul = cv2.multiply(alpha1i,alpha2i)

# converting to 8-bit
mulint = cv2.normalize(mul, dst=None, alpha=0, beta=255,norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_8U)

# again create 3-channel mask of float data type
alpha = cv2.cvtColor(mulint[:,:,2], cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGRA)/255.0

# perform blending using previous output and multiplied result
final = cv2.convertScaleAbs(b1i*(1-alpha) + mulint*alpha)
```

[image]

Sorry for the weird variable names. I would request you to analyze the result in each line. I hope this is the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You could use PIL library to achieve this

```
from PIL import Image

def merge_images(im1, im2):
    bg = Image.open(im1).convert("RGBA")
    fg = Image.open(im2).convert("RGBA")
    x, y = ((bg.width - fg.width) // 2 , (bg.height - fg.height) // 2)
    bg.paste(fg, (x, y), fg)
    # convert to 8 bits (pallete mode)
    return bg.convert("P")
```

we can test it using the provided images:

```
result_image = merge_images("image1.png", "image2.png")
result_image.save("image3.png")
```

Here's the result:

[image: image3.png]

Comment: Yes I've already tried it but It's doesn't give the exact expected result. Here's the difference between what I've got using PIL and what I've got using Photoshop : [difference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90pk1.png)